# What is the proper way to use WebSocketClient ReceiveAsync and buffer?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, websocket

I want to create a Bot class in C# for [slack](https://api.slack.com/) to let services create and consume messages for our company.  To make it easy for our services to use, I have it just called with `Connect()` and use an event to let the caller know when there's a message.  This is basically how it will be called:

```
SlackBot bot = new SlackBot(TOKEN);
bot.OnReceiveMessage += message => {
    Console.WriteLine("DELEGATE GOT MESSAGE: '{0}'", message);
};
bot.Connect();
```

The `Connect()` method calls an internal `Receive()` method that calls itself after every message:

```
public delegate void MessageReceivedDelegate(string message);

public event MessageReceivedDelegate OnReceiveMessage;

void Receive()
{
    _ReceiveTask = _Client.ReceiveAsync(_ClientBuffer, _CancellationToken);
    _ReceiveTask.ContinueWith(twsrr =>
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = twsrr.Result;
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_ClientBuffer.Array,
             _ClientBuffer.Offset, result.Count);
        OnReceiveMessage(message);
        Receive();
    });
}
```

So the largest buffer acceptable is 64k, do I need to check `result.EndOfMessage` and use a MemoryStream or something to to keep adding bytes to until I get the end of the message, then send it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the RFC, that seems to be the case to me. I'm less familiar with the WebSocket protocol than the underlying TCP and other network protocols, but if on each call to `ReceiveAsync()` you actually received a complete message, there would not seem to be a need for the `EndOfMessage` property on the result.

Note also that your code could benefit from being written in the `async`/`await` pattern:

```
async Task Receive()
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await _Client.ReceiveAsync(_ClientBuffer, _CancellationToken);

    if (result.Count != 0 || result.CloseStatus == WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty)
    {
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_ClientBuffer.Array,
             _ClientBuffer.Offset, result.Count);
        OnReceiveMessage(message);
        await Receive();
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer, change the `Receive()` to `async` but leave it as `void` and don't await it. It's an exception to the general rule for `async` methods, but it would avoid the I/O building a chain of continuations that only gets resolved when the connection is actually closed.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but I have a warning (I hate warnings) in my Connect() which calls receive.  I don't want the connect to be asynchronous, I want to wait until it is connected and then have it just fire my `OnReceiveMessge()` delegate.  Is there a way to get rid of that warning, barring ignoring it everywhere?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: ideally, the way to get rid of warnings is to go ahead and make things `async` (i.e. including the `Connect()` method). That said, you can avoid the warnings if the method returns `void` instead of `Task`, or if you store the return value in a local variable (which you then ignore). In _some_ cases, those are acceptable alternatives...normally you shouldn't ignore the warnings, but if you're sure the behavior is what you want (including not being able to await completion or catch exceptions in the task), then you can do it that way.